# Does anyone assign significance to the `Leader` process in a systemd-logind session?

Tags: systemd, pam, logind

The first process in a `pam_systemd` session is called the `Leader`.  E.g. it can be killed with `loginctl --kill-who=leader kill-session SESSION_ID`.

`pam_systemd` puts the leader in a session scope unit.  Interestingly if this is the main process of a systemd service, this means process leaves the cgroup of the service; systemd explicitly supports this.  However the leader could also choose to escape the session scope.

```
User=root
PAMName=i-wanna-be-a-systemd-logind-session
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-run --scope --unit=not-a-session.scope sleep 600
```

This should leave behind a child process called `(sd-pam)` in the session scope, which runs pam_session_close() when the parent terminates.  So the session scope unit will remain active.

I think this should also be possible with an unpriviliged user and `systemd-run --user --scope`.

If the user doesn't explicitly make a request regarding the `Leader` e.g. with `loginctl`, would these shenanigans have any significance?  What I'm really wondering is if this could break something.

Is the `Leader` value really used for anything, or is it mainly for display purposes?  Is there any known rationale or use case for supporting `loginctl --kill-who=leader kill-session SESSION_ID`, that might shed light on this question?